# Как полностью получить данные с помощью recv?

Tags: macos, c, сокет

Сервер читает сначала запрос от клиента, которые умещается в 10 байт:

```
recv(sock, &buf, 10, 0);
```

Мне нужно знать как работает `recv`. Как известно данные могут придти не все сразу, а частями. И как в таком случае поступает `recv`, если ему явно указано прочитать 10 байт? `recv` отработает сам до конца или необходимо вручную проверять возвращаемое значение `recv()` и в случае не "доздачи" запустить цикл снова?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция возвращает количество полученных байт. А параметр резервирует буфер (т.е. максимальное ожидаемое значение).

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Receiving-Data.html

```
    const size_t BUF_SIZE = 10;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE ];
    size_t nRecieved = 0;

// с флагом "MSG_WAITALL" ждем заполнения буфера
    nRecieved = recv(sock, &buf, BUF_SIZE , MSG_WAITALL );
    if (nRecieved != -1)
    {
        /* ... */
    }
```

В буфере нам будут интересные первые `nRecieved` байт.

Comment: Т.е. если `recv` получить, к примеру сначала 6 байт, он не станет ждать оставшийся пакет и возратив 6 завершит свою работу?

Comment: @derkode
Ну читайте же референс по ссылке =( "If nonblocking mode is set for socket, and no data are available to be read, recv fails immediately rather than waiting...."

"Normally, recv blocks until there is input available to be read"

Comment: @derkode
Погуглив, мне кажется, что она сразу получает все доступное.
Хотя, я с этим дело не имел, мне верить нельзя))
Но, вроде бы, ей можно дать флаг MSG_WAITALL, с которым функция будет блокировать поток до тех пор, пока буфер не заполнится.

Comment: Из линукс `man 2 recv`

     MSG_WAITALL (since Linux 2.2)
              This flag requests that the operation block until the full  request
              is  satisfied.   However,  the call may still return less data than
              requested if a signal is caught, an error or disconnect occurs,  or
              the  next  data  to  be  received  is of a different type than that
              returned.


@derkode, другими словами, если Вы будете корректно программировать, то результат вызова `recv` все равно проверять надо.